Will my tankless water heater run on just one or two 40 amp breakers
Will my tankless water heater run on just one of the three 40 Amp breakers?

At best it might warm up cold water to cool water.  That typo might come true if you tried.

thankless water heater
I know that was a typo (perhaps auto-correct), but it fits so well!
Tankless water heaters are a bit of a mess. The concept is simple: heat water as needed, don't waste energy, don't need a lot of space. The problem is they need a LOT of power. 3 x 40A is typical - that's ~ 27 kW. According to this specifications page from Rheem that will get you:

2 GPM at 92 degree rise
2.5 GPM at 74 degree rise
3 GPM at 62 degree rise
4 GPM at 46 degree rise
5 GPM at 37 degree rise

which means, for example, that if your incoming water is at 40 degrees, typical in many places in the winter, you will only get around 3 GPM of hot water. Which is OK if you have a small household and manage things reasonably well - e.g., don't run the dishwasher when you are about to take a shower.
However, if you only connect two of the circuits then you only get 2/3 the output - e.g., 2 GPM at 62 degree rise. And if you only connect one of the circuits then you only get 1/3 the output - e.g., 1 GPM at 62 degree rise. In other words, it will work but not very well. Well, it will probably work - you have to make sure to connect the circuit that also handles the controls, but that should be easy enough to figure out.
If you need to do this temporarily - e.g., while waiting to do a service upgrade - then it is OK. If you need to do this permanently then either get a smaller tankless water heater or get a traditional tank water heater.
Also note that if you simply connect 2 or 3 of the sets of connections to one 40A circuit then you will either trip the breaker every time you use the water heater for more than a few seconds (ideal) or burn down your house (if your breakers fail, which can happen, particularly with certain brands that are now off-the-market but still installed in many homes).
